# Expandable tableview cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My current `tableview` expands the cells on click, example:

```
Parent 0

   -Child 1

   -Child 2

   -Child 3
```

What I'm struggling to do is, when I expand a cell all the others will close, I'm trying to make sure only one cell Is open at the time. Can you guys give any ideas on how to do it?

Current code for expanding the cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.section==0) {

    if([d valueForKey:@"produtos"]) {
        NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"produtos"];

        BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;

        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
            NSInteger index=[self.firstForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
        }

        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar];
        } else {
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.firstForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }

            [tableView1 beginUpdates];
            [tableView1 insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [tableView1 endUpdates];
            [tableView1 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

        }

    }else{
        NSLog(@"child %@ %@|",[item valueForKey:@"nome"],[item valueForKey:@"produtos"]);
    }
}
```

Current code for minimizing the cell:

```
-(void)miniMizeFirstsRows:(NSArray*)ar{
NSLog(@"miniMizeFirstsRows");
for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
    NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.firstForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
    NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"produtos"];
    if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
        [self miniMizeFirstsRows:arInner];
    }

    if([self.firstForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
        [self.firstForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                                [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]
                                                ]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
         [tableView endUpdates];
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT still Can't make it work**
What I have, by using the help from Marco answer:

```
 NSLog(@"indexPath1 = %i",selectedRow);

        NSDictionary *d=[self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
            NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row +1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.firstForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            //   }
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"Leave Element:::%@ %@|",[d valueForKey:@"name"],[d valueForKey:@"book"]);
        }

    // The user is selecting the cell which is currently expanded
    // we want to minimize it back
    if (selectedRow == row)
    {

        NSLog(@"selectedRow2 = %i",selectedRow);

        NSDictionary *d=[self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
        if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
            NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

            [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar];

        }

        selectedRow = -1;

        return;
    }

    // First we check if a cell is already expanded.
    // If it is we want to minimize make sure it is reloaded to minimize it back
    if (selectedRow >= 0)
    {

        NSLog(@"selectedRow3 = %i",selectedRow);

        NSDictionary *d=[self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
        if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
            NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

            [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar];

        }
        selectedRow = row;
    }

    // Finally set the selected index to the new selection and reload it to expan
    selectedRow = row;
    [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Some more help please :)

Comment: check this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ratreeview

Comment: Thanks :) but the control is way to complex for my needs and it expands multiple cells, wish is not the behavior I want. I want one cell expanded at the time, and when I expand one cell, all the other should close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need an instance variable to track your selected cell.

NOTE: The code below is not meant to replace your tableview data source and delegate methods, but as an example to track a selected cell:

Add an `NSInteger selectedRow` instance variable to your view controller.

In `viewDidLoad`, initialize `selectedRow` to indicate no cell will be expanded:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set set our selectedRow to -1 to indicate no cell will be expanded
    selectedRow = -1;
}
```

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    // The user is selecting the cell which is currently expanded
    // we want to minimize it back
    if (selectedRow == row)
    {
        selectedRow = -1;
        [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];

        return;
    }

    // First we check if a cell is already expanded.
    // If it is we want to minimize make sure it is reloaded to minimize it back
    if (selectedRow >= 0)
    {
        selectedRow = row;
    }

    // Finally set the selected index to the new selection and reload it to expand
    selectedRow = row;
    [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: If the only thing you're changing is the cell height, reloading the rows will cause a flickering effect since the content will be identical.  You can just do `[tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];` without reloading any rows and any height changes will be automatically animated.

Comment: @AaronBrager you're right, updated/simplified code accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marco and Aaron but I still can't make it work, I have edited the main post to show what I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

One thing missing from Marco's answer is the implementation of "heightForRowAtIndexPath" Delegate method.
So these are the steps you need to follow:

1. Create a variable to record the selected row number
2. Update that variable when a row is selected (in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" delegate method) and call tableView's **beginUpdates** & **endUpdates** methods.
3. Return bigger height when **indexPath.row == selectedRow**, else return normal height.